# Variable argument constructor _may_ conflict, but compiles

Tags: java, constructor, variadic-functions

I have two constructors that compile just fine but I'd expect Java to complain about the possibility of ambiguity.

```
public Foo(int id, Bar bar, String name, String description){
}

public Foo(int id, Bar bar, String... values){
}
```

What gives?

Comment: +1 Good question. I misinterpreted your question at first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java allows these methods to exist, because it has rules about which one will be called if both apply.  Specifically, the fixed arity method (without `...`) will be chosen over the variable arity method (with `...`).

The [JLS, Section 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), states the following when determining which method is chosen:

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without
>   permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity
>   method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase
>   then processing continues to the second phase.
>
> This guarantees that any calls that were valid in the Java programming
>   language before Java SE 5.0 are not considered ambiguous as the result
>   of the introduction of variable arity methods, implicit boxing and/or
>   unboxing. However, the declaration of a variable arity method (§8.4.1)
>   can change the method chosen for a given method method invocation
>   expression, because a variable arity method is treated as a fixed
>   arity method in the first phase. For example, declaring m(Object...)
>   in a class which already declares m(Object) causes m(Object) to no
>   longer be chosen for some invocation expressions (such as m(null)), as
>   m(Object[]) is more specific.
>
> The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while
>   allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable
>   arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this
>   phase then processing continues to the third phase.
>
> **This ensures that a method is never chosen through variable arity
>   method invocation if it is applicable through fixed arity method
>   invocation.**
>
> The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with
>   variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

(emphasis mine)

Example code:

```
class Bar{}

public class Foo{
   public static void main (String [] args){
      Foo main = new Foo(1, new Bar(), "name", "description");
      Foo main2 = new Foo(2, new Bar(), "name");
      Foo main3 = new Foo(3, new Bar(), "name", "description", "otherValues");
      Foo main4 = new Foo(4, new Bar());    
   }

   public Foo(int id, Bar bar, String name, String description) {
      System.out.println("name and description!");
   }

   public Foo(int id, Bar bar, String... values) {
      System.out.println("values!");
   }
}
```

This prints out:

```
name and description!
values!
values!
values!
```

... to show that Java will pick the fixed arity method if it can.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you Sean, the following code could be calling any of the two constructors you defined:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(3, new Bar(), "", "");
```

However, when the java people introduced the "variable argument notation", they decided that the above would call "the most especific constructor" defined. In this case I have 2 String arguments, and your first constructor needs exactly 2 String arguments, so it will be called.
The second constructor will be called only if there are more or less than 2 String arguments, for example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(3, new Bar(), "", "", "");
```

Or even:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(3, new Bar());
```

I hope that helps to clarify why you don't get the compiler to complain about it (it´s just the way they decided it should work).